# Putting product in shopping cart makes it disappear in cypress

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e-testing, shopping-cart, e2e

I'm an intern at an tech company and I've got the task to try to write some tests. I'm not a dev,nor an engineer, I'm actually studying economics so please forgive any newbie mistakes.

My goal is to test what is shown in the shopping cart after I put a lottery ticket in. I want to test every variety (with bonus games etc.) and if those varities (for example, put 4 tickets in shopping cart -> shows 4 Tickets in shopping cart)

````
describe('visit page', IPHONE_X, () => {
    it('visit page Lotto 6aus49', () => {
        cy.visit('/lotto')
    })
})
describe('filling ticket and proceeding to basket', IPHONE_X, () => {
    it('quicktip ticket click', () => {
        cy.get('ticketbutton').click()
    })
    it('basket button click', () => {
        cy.get('submit-to-basket-button').click()
    })
/// what happens here is that the interface switches to another one. If I test the case cypress shows me that the basket is empty. Why is that? I mean, that's why I clicked all those buttons before.
    it('basket contains right weekday of ticket', () => {
        cy.get('basket-item').contains("Ticket Lottery Example")```

I hope that I described my case understandable. Thank you.
````

Comment: Technically it should work the way you have it. The browser stays in the same state between tests. It is tempting to use lot's of `it()` to mark the steps, but if you combine those `it()` does it resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all the answers. Didn't except such a great community.

Here is how I solved this problem:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands